# Working in the USA moving back to Canada

Tags: 401k, visa

I am a Canadian currently working in the US for a company that offers a 401K. If I move back to Canada let's say half way through the year, is my 401K contribution limit prorated from $18500 to $9250? Is the same true when I enter the US?

Thanks!